# Digital ocean server access issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, pkill

I have accidentally run command pkill -U root.
I was in root user..
now I am not able to access through ssh from my local system but I can access my server's terminal on my browser from my digitl ocean account.

Comment: Probably just want to restart the server.  You probably killed several processes that are required for various things, including sshd.

Comment: @Jesse_b Please help with some commands..

Comment: `/sbin/shutdown -r now`

Comment: will it shutdown the server..?
if yes then what about restart

Comment: It will restart the server which includes shutting it down.  If you are unable to restart the server because it's in production you probably shouldn't have been running `pkill` commands on it willy nilly in the first place.  It's very likely that whatever is running on it isn't working or isn't working as it should anyway so you might as well just rip the band aid off.

Comment: it worked thank you @Jesse_b
and sure I'll be more careful next time...